# Filter QgsAttributeTableModel without geometry

Tags: pyqgis

Is it possible to filter a `QgsAttributeTableModel` without geometries.
I was not able to filter a `QgsAttributeTableModel` without geometries, so I added a fake geometry column to my table (`"geom_fake"`). Now it works, as I want.

I am working on a QGIS plugin and I want to display data in tables, sometime with and sometime without geometries. So I use a `QgsAttributeTableModel` to achieve this.

Is there a smarter solution to filter tables without geometries (like in QGIS, where you can filter tables with or without geometries very easy).

**Addition:**

I am using QGIS 3.4 with a SpatiaLite-database (SQLite) created with QGIS.
Here is a summary of the used code (this is not a working example).

First I set the model and the tableview:

```
self.layer_uri = '''dbname='C:/Daten/db/GisDaten.sqlite' table="alm_gdb_main" (geom_fake) sql='''
self.layer = QgsVectorLayer(self.layer_uri, 'GDB-Grundstücke', 'spatialite')
self.layer.getFeatures()

self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

self.vector_layer_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(self.layer, 10000)
self.attribute_table_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(self.vector_layer_cache, self)
self.attribute_table_model.loadLayer()

self.filter_mod = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(self.canvas, self.main_table_model, self)

self.uiMainListTblvw = QgsAttributeTableView(self)
self.uiMainListTblvw.setModel(self.filter_mod)
```

to filter the model call the following code:

```
selection = self.layer.getFeatures(gsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(self.filterString.text()))
ids = [i.id() for i in selection]
self.filter_mod.setFilterMode(3)
self.filter_mod.setFilteredFeatures(ids)
```

`self.filterString` is a lineedit where you can enter the filterstring for testing.

This code above works as I want, when the layer has a geometry column.
To handle a layer without a geometry-column i would change `self.layer_uri` to `dbname='C:/Daten/db/GisDaten.sqlite' table="alm_gdb_main" sql=`.
But now the filter doesn't work correctly anymore.

Comment: Can you please add the code you have written, then it is a bit easier to see what is going on. - also which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: I have added some addition infos and a code-summary